# Poincaré Duality with de Rham Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This is probably a fairly basic question:

Poincaré Duality states the following: Given an $n$-manifold, the $k^{th}$ homology is isomorphic to the $(n-k)^{th}$ cohomology.

So I was curious is there some certain relation you get when dealing with de Rham cohomology? For example lets take the punctured plane, then the 1st cohomology group is simply $\mathbb{R}$. However, when looking at the first homotopy group of the punctured plane, we get $\mathbb{Z}$.

But, these two groups are not isomorphic. What am I missing?

Comment: Dear Benjamin, The relationship between homotopy and homology with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients (to the extent that there is one) is given by the Hurewicz theorem.  The relationship between homology with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ coefficients is given by universal coefficients.  Also, Poincare duality holds for *closed* manifolds (and so does not apply, at least in the naive form that you have stated it, to a non-compact manifold such as the punctured plane).  Regards,

Comment: @Matt E: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Brandon: Dear Brandon, I thought at first that the OP may have been looking for something more substantive.  I will post a version as answer, though.  Regards,

Comment: When you allow the manifold to have boundary, frequently people call the appropriately-generalized version of Poincare Duality that applies to that situation *Alexander Duality*. It's also frequently phrased as $H_i(M,X) \simeq H^{m-i}(M,Y)$ where $X \sqcup Y = \partial M$.

Comment: There is a version Poincare duality between de Rham cohomology and compactly-supported de Rham cohomology.  You can read about this in Section I of Bott & Tu's beautiful book, "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology".

Answer (score 29):

Here are some remarks related to the questions you raise:

First of all, you mention *homotopy* groups, rather than homology groups.
The relationship between homotopy and homology with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients (to the extent that there is one) is given by the [Hurewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem).   In any event, in discussing Poincaré duality, it is *homology* and *cohomology* groups that are directly relevant, rather than homotopy groups.

The relationship between singular homology with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ coefficients is given by the [universal coefficient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem).  It states that
$H_i(X,\mathbb R) = H_i(X,\mathbb Z)\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R.$  (In general, there would be a Tor contribution as well, but that vanishes here, since $\mathbb R$ is torsion free.)

The [de Rham Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham.27s_theorem)
states that the $k$th de Rham cohomology of a smooth manifold is isomorphic to
the $k$th singular cohomology of the manifold with $\mathbb R$-coefficients,
or, equivalently (by [universal coefficients for cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology)), is dual to the $k$th singular homology with $\mathbb R$-coefficients.

Poincaré duality itself, when phrased in terms of de Rham cohomology, states that for a *closed*, connected, and orientable $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, the $n$th de Rham cohomology group $H^n$ is one-dimensional over $\mathbb R$, and  the cup product from
$H^k \times H^{n-k}$ to $H^n$ (which in de Rham cohomology is induced by wedge product on forms) is a perfect pairing.

Taking into account the relationship between de Rham and singular theory stated above, this can also be phrased as an isomorphism between $H^{n-k}$ and $H_k$ with $\mathbb R$-coefficients.  But note that the homology under consideration has $\mathbb R$-coefficients, not $\mathbb Z$-coefficients!  Note also that Poincaré duality is a statement for closed manifolds (and so does not apply, at least in the naive form that you have stated it, to a non-compact manifold such as the punctured plane).

There is a version of Poincaré duality with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients (as well as generalizations to non-closed and/or non-orientable manifolds); see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_duality).  Note though that if you want to consider homology with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients, then you will also need to consider cohomology with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients, and de Rham theory doesn't do this.  (You will need to use some other form of cohomology, such as singular, Cech, or sheaf cohomology.)

Comment: Not widely known about duality and Hodge star for closed oriented Riemannian, although you may have seen this already: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3134/whats-your-favorite-equation-formula-identity-or-inequality/17139#17139

Comment: @Will: Dear Will, Thanks for the link, and also for implictly reminding me to add the adjective *orientable* to the above discussion.  Regards,