# If $\omega\wedge\beta$ is exact for every closed form $\beta$, then $\omega$ is exact.

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $\omega$ be a closed $k$-form. Then:

> If $\omega$ is exact, for every *closed* form $\beta$, the form $\omega\wedge\beta$ is exact.

Proof: Let $\omega=d\alpha$. Now $d(\alpha\wedge\beta) = d\alpha\wedge\beta +(-1)^k\alpha\wedge d\beta = \omega\wedge\beta + 0$, since $d\beta=0$ by hypothesis.

I want to prove the converse. Let $\omega$ be a closed $k$-form, again. Then:

> If for every closed form $\beta$ the form $\omega\wedge\beta$ is exact, then $\omega$ is exact.

How can I prove the latter statement?

(If one uses de Rham currents, this question is linked to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770206/show-that-omega-is-exact-if-and-only-if-the-integral-of-omega-over-every-p).)

Comment: If the underlying manifold is compact then this follows from (or rather is) the perfectness of the intersection pairing in Poincaré duality. In the general case I'm not sure what happens.

Comment: Does it hold for $\beta$ a constant $0$-form?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ha, that is neat. But I would rather need $\beta$ to be of degree $n-k$ for the linked question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false without compactness. Every $2$-form on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ is exact, but the infamous $1$-form $d\theta$ is not.

Comment: Right. I need a slightly different hypothesis. When I've found it, I'll post a new question.